# Is there any compression method in java to reduce the number of charaters in a string?

Tags: java, string, gzip

I am currently facing a problem while compressing a string to fewer characters in java.

I have a huge string which is about 751396 characters and there is a requirement of compressing the string into a 1500 characters.

I have tried GZIP Compressor, Inflater & Deflater but these libraries return byte arrays

Then I tried LZ-String compressor in which I was able to get satisfactory results using UTF16 encoding and `base64` encoding, But these compression return some characters which are neither alphanumeric nor are they included in the symbols list provided.

**N.B.** The list for the Symbols is [+,-,*,/,!,@,#]

is there any other technique of compressing the string into another string with fewer characters and providing at least 30% of compression ratio.

**The codes which I am using for GZip compression is as follows:-**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class GZIPCompression {

    public static byte[] compress(final String str) throws IOException {
        if ((str == null) || (str.length() == 0)) {
            return null;
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
        gzip.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        gzip.close();
        return obj.toByteArray();
    }

    public static String decompress(final byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
        String outStr = "";
        if ((compressed == null) || (compressed.length == 0)) {
            return "";
        }
        if (isCompressed(compressed)) {
            GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                outStr += line;
            }
        } else {
            outStr = new String(compressed);
        }
        return outStr;
    }

    public static boolean isCompressed(final byte[] compressed) {
        return (compressed[0] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC)) && (compressed[1] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC >> 8));
    }
}
```

**The code for the Inflater &  Deflater program is as follows:-**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class Apple {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sr = "    [120,-100,-19,89,91,79,-21,56,16,-2,43,40,-49,104,55,113,-18,-68,-91,-23,21,104,90,-38,-62,10,-83,120,48,-83,91,34,-46,-92,-21,-92,8,-124,-8,-17,103,-100,-92,77,-22,-38,-25,112,86,27,-119,106,65,84,-86,103,-58,-10,124,-98,-15,101,-66,-66,43,25,126,-99,-112,116,-109,-60,41,81,46,-34,-107,-57,36,121,14,-29,-43,-20,109,3,77,101,-94,-100,43,120,-79,-115,50,63,-39,-58,25,8,52,16,-52,-97,-62,104,-79,19,-88,32,8,-29,37,-114,-77,-70,-92,71,-78,89,125,-36,-65,-33,-107,5,-50,-40,-120,-86,-11,39,82,-31,95,-77,-40,-48,-21,-94,15,82,13,11,-58,-115,112,-102,-6,-55,-126,-103,-7,126,-65,53,-22,-113,-64,-58,123,-63,97,52,37,-85,53,97,-106,-17,74,55,10,87,79,-39,96,-63,-100,65,76,31,-46,40,-116,73,-39,111,-38,3,81,97,18,108,-41,-113,-124,-126,-52,-48,-100,-62,-50,-89,120,-103,-107,-56,108,-99,9,71,52,92,-123,49,52,91,-41,-109,125,19,44,55,9,-51,102,-124,-82,-61,24,71,-96,5,85,-101,-92,25,-76,-78,48,-55,-51,71,-61,67,-103,-92,-49,6,-45,108,75,73,27,-80,-49,-62,53,-101,23,-64,-25,75,-96,89,103,72,-67,48,-44,11,-107,-83,-105,71,105,-8,-126,35,-119,29,-70,-48,74,-69,-10,-106,-18,92,-48,-98,104,122,-90,-85,48,93,10,-118,2,108,-78,-100,102,-55,38,85,46,-44,115,-27,46,-60,-123,23,-2,-106,82,18,-49,-33,-54,21,26,4,-109,-35,-86,-114,-15,107,23,-125,119,36,-125,70,-102,71,-55,23,-58,96,47,5,-60,-13,-61,-24,-80,-28,96,97,105,-31,52,-100,123,101,60,53,-61,112,33,12,48,54,19,-61,-56,74,-112,116,41,-127,-42,74,41,-28,-69,-4,34,-53,109,-68,-64,-113,17,1,-7,-3,77,-18,-8,44,-55,112,4,-39,-77,27,12,68,61,-102,-92,-23,126,112,-45,48,-64,-91,100,-67,14,-45,-76,88,11,-45,-2,-61,-75,-108,-113,-113,-13,67,0,-99,-114,12,64,-91,17,3,-128,-124,108,14,0,-46,28,-99,3,-32,104,66,0,-35,-82,12,64,-91,-111,0,48,-35,6,1,-40,-74,-54,1,-48,84,93,-120,-96,-33,-105,33,-88,52,98,4,-70,-34,96,8,116,-45,114,121,4,-70,24,-63,-27,-91,12,65,-91,-111,32,112,27,-116,-127,-127,44,-115,71,96,-70,66,4,87,87,50,4,-107,70,-116,-64,112,26,-116,-127,-87,89,54,-113,-64,21,-57,-32,-6,90,-122,-96,-46,-120,17,-104,77,34,-80,-112,-50,111,100,36,-55,-94,-31,80,-122,-96,-46,-120,17,-40,77,30,69,-74,-87,-15,89,-124,36,103,81,16,-56,16,84,26,49,2,71,111,112,31,56,-82,-55,-97,69,-70,110,10,17,-116,70,50,4,-107,70,-116,-64,117,26,68,-96,-87,-90,-31,-16,16,92,49,-124,-101,27,25,-124,74,35,-71,-110,-31,-38,108,16,3,-46,85,126,51,27,-106,56,-111,38,19,25,-122,74,35,-63,-48,-24,-99,-96,25,8,-103,-4,-61,66,-78,-99,-89,83,25,-122,74,35,-63,96,-94,38,115,-55,-46,85,-2,72,-78,52,113,28,102,51,25,-122,74,35,-63,96,55,-71,-93,53,-57,52,-8,45,109,-19,-10,-61,-61,-57,-71,-78,43,43,-90,25,-50,-74,48,57,-100,96,-73,41,-95,51,-118,-25,-49,121,93,48,25,-34,-113,6,-82,-83,-62,-3,91,124,116,-37,-123,67,-56,50,12,3,-23,-102,-19,-72,-106,-125,92,56,-25,-64,39,-16,99,-76,-51,54,-37,18,-28,106,-123,87,-60,-117,23,67,-126,-93,-76,27,1,-100,-36,-29,-68,-108,41,-86,-118,-78,18,41,94,-53,71,-75,8,91,46,-80,-50,-21,20,-74,58,-108,-32,-25,-37,-51,-2,-127,93,-82,-93,-16,69,46,20,10,94,-43,-99,127,-74,-84,84,0,31,-40,12,59,41,76,90,127,-58,-77,64,-46,112,83,-106,10,-29,105,-105,57,-73,-49,64,-107,-91,-62,-95,-55,109,-69,110,-94,-101,-24,-40,-92,55,-99,-43,76,28,-29,-40,-30,-22,-54,-81,15,-14,-15,112,28,108,-45,97,-50,82,28,-89,120,-50,122,117,9,-55,-105,120,74,-24,75,56,39,-2,19,-90,43,-112,56,-4,-117,51,47,16,-123,111,126,54,-53,-124,-64,-94,80,-78,-24,-122,36,90,-28,-21,-100,71,2,-60,53,-55,42,-65,-59,-64,-63,-63,98,76,-109,100,89,-74,-58,-112,-5,-84,116,-37,-105,-117,65,94,-65,-58,-117,-68,113,-49,-118,46,-88,-54,70,-53,86,72,-77,39,-82,79,-25,117,19,-46,-73,118,81,-39,-42,21,-125,52,-35,66,21,-99,-105,-60,-12,-83,84,6,121,-23,-122,-93,48,43,36,-112,-54,62,43,-91,-65,-66,-101,-125,-68,-64,111,-60,-49,-5,-1,-50,79,112,52,-33,-73,-5,-8,-105,45,-40,15,-20,91,-71,-79,-18,122,67,118,-78,49,-55,97,-10,6,-55,89,-47,-95,80,-18,-113,39,-106,-25,-121,-3,-81,-123,-3,107,-118,-86,80,50,-71,-34,99,-65,-27,11,123,-113,59,94,112,59,-101,-98,121,65,-5,-84,-43,-71,-13,38,94,-81,-61,-115,-90,25,-68,47,-63,-99,-60,-105,-102,66,-18,75,32,-13,37,-16,-4,-2,-24,55,93,-71,12,36,-82,92,122,-125,-32,108,-40,-15,120,127,116,-109,31,-94,-35,-110,12,-47,30,120,-83,-50,108,-32,127,110,24,95,6,-53,-9,-90,-3,-65,58,-97,89,-27,-121,-113,-4,-74,-84,81,86,-58,17,101,5,23,-54,33,101,85,-29,20,126,66,89,-63,-33,39,73,43,-3,-41,-92,85,-50,66,125,-98,-76,-54,57,-82,127,69,90,25,123,50,74,117,-10,100,-108,-128,-76,-86,-20,-64,72,64,90,33,70,90,53,-55,89,125,85,-54,7,-23,-4,-3,117,98,-108,-113,-125,-8,119,-27,-87,81,62,22,66,39,78,-7,-24,26,79,124,-98,26,-27,-125,-48,17,113,120,106,-108,-113,-61,111,-28,-109,-93,124,44,62,-117,78,-116,-14,113,-43,-93,26,-9,-28,40,31,75,-27,121,-73,19,-92,124,44,126,51,-97,32,-27,99,-13,-44,-37,9,82,62,38,127,36,-99,32,-27,-29,30,-47,86,95,-97,-14,41,-33,-14,-115,-110,62,-59,-77,-108,39,125,10,-23,79,73,-97,-39,-92,-50,-24,-120,56,-97,-33,-90,-123,12,83,-1,21,45,-92,33,1,115,116,-56,11,25,34,94,-56,-74,63,-59,11,-79,95,43,-72,119,-87,-50,-1,-112,-73,-69,-52,-66,-119,-95,-26,-35,-4,38,-122,-66,-119,-95,-1,27,49,4,-97,31,15,0,-88,84]";
        byte[] data = sr.getBytes();
        try {
            String x = new String(decompress(compress(data)));
            System.out.println("decompressed " + x);
        } catch (IOException | DataFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] compress(byte[] data) throws IOException {
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setInput(data);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);

        deflater.finish();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (!deflater.finished()) {
            int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();

        System.out.println("Original: " + data.length);
        System.out.println("Compressed: " + output.length);
        return output;
    }

    public static byte[] decompress(byte[] data) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        inflater.setInput(data);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (!inflater.finished()) {
            int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
        System.out.println();
        return output;
    } 
}
```

A sample of how the data will look like:-

```
"120,-100,-19,89,91,79,-21,56,16,-2,43,40,-49,104,55,113,-18,-68,-91,-23,21,104,90,-38,-62,10,-83,120,48,-83,91,34,-46,-92,-21,-92,8,-124,-8,-17,103,-100,-92,77,-22,-38,-25,112,86,27,-119,106,65,84,-86,103,-58,-10,124,-98,-15,101,-66,-66,43,25,126,-99,-112,116,-109,-60,41,81,46,-34,-107,-57,36,121,14,-29,-43,-20,109,3,77,101,-94,-100,43,120,-79,-115,50,63,-39,-58,25,8,52,16,-52,-97,-62,104,-79,19,-88,32,8,-29,37,-114,-77,-70,-92,71,-78,89,125,-36,-65,-33,-107,5,-50,-40,-120,-86,-11,39,82,-31,95,-77,-40,-48,-21,-94,15,82,13,11,-58,-115,112,-102,-6,-55,-126,-103,-7,126,-65,53,-22,-113,-64,-58,123,-63,97,52,37,-85,53,97,-106,-17,74,55,10,87,79,-39,96,-63,-100,65,76,31,-46,40,-116,73,-39,111,-38,3,81,97,18,108,-41,-113,-124,-126,-52,-48,-100,-62,-50,-89,120,-103,-107,-56,108,-99,9,71,52,92,-123,49,52,91,-41,-109,125,19,44,55,9,-51,102,-124,-82,-61,24,71,-96,5,85,-101,-92,25,-76,-78,48,-55,-51,71,-61,67,-103,-92,-49,6,-45,108,75,73,27,-80,-49,-62,53,-101,23,-64,-25,75,-96,89,103,72,-67,48,-44,11,-107,-83,-105,71,105,-8,-126,35,-119,29,-70,-48,74,-69,-10,-106,-18,92,-48,-98,104,122,-90,-85,48,93,10,-118,2,108,-78,-100,102,-55,38,85,46,-44,115,-27,46,-60,-123,23,-2,-106,82,18,-49,-33,-54,21,26,4,-109,-35,-86,-114,-15,107,23,-125,119,36,-125,70,-102,71,-55,23,-58,96,47,5,-60,-13,-61,-24,-80,-28,96,97,105,-31,52,-100,123,101,60,53,-61,112,33,12,48,54,19,-61,-56,74,-112,116,41,-127,-42,74,41,-28,-69,-4,34,-53,109,-68,-64,-113,17,1,-7,-3,77,-18,-8,44,-55,112,4,-39,-77,27,12,68,61,-102,-92,-23,126,112,-45,48,-64,-91,100,-67,14,-45,-76,88,11,-45,-2,-61,-75,-108,-113,-113,-13,67,0,-99,-114,12,64,-91,17,3,-128,-124,108,14,0,-46,28,-99,3,-32,104,66,0,-35,-82,12,64,-91,-111,0,48,-35,6,1,-40,-74,-54,1,-48,84,93,-120,-96,-33,-105,33,-88,52,98,4,-70,-34,96,8,116,-45,114,121,4,-70,24,-63,-27,-91,12,65,-91,-111,32,112,27,-116,-127,-127,44,-115,71,96,-70,66,4,87,87,50,4,-107,70,-116,-64,112,26,-116,-127,-87,89,54,-113,-64,21,-57,-32,-6,90,-122,-96,-46,-120,17,-104,77,34,-80,-112,-50,111,100,36,-55,-94,-31,80,-122,-96,-46,-120,17,-40,77,30,69,-74,-87,-15,89,-124,36,103,81,16,-56,16,84,26,49,2,71,111,112,31,56,-82,-55,-97,69,-70,110,10,17,-116,70,50,4,-107,70,-116,-64,117,26,68,-96,-87,-90,-31,-16,16,92,49,-124,-101,27,25,-124,74,35,-71,-110,-31,-38,108,16,3,-46,85,126,51,27,-106,56,-111,38,19,25,-122,74,35,-63,-48,-24,-99,-96,25,8,-103,-4,-61,66,-78,-99,-89,83,25,-122,74,35,-63,96,-94,38,115,-55,-46,85,-2,72,-78,52,113,28,102,51,25,-122,74,35,-63,96,55,-71,-93,53,-57,52,-8,45,109,-19,-10,-61,-61,-57,-71,-78,43,43,-90,25,-50,-74,48,57,-100,96,-73,41,-95,51,-118,-25,-49,121,93,48,25,-34,-113,6,-82,-83,-62,-3,91,124,116,-37,-123,67,-56,50,12,3,-23,-102,-19,-72,-106,-125,92,56,-25,-64,39,-16,99,-76,-51,54,-37,18,-28,106,-123,87,-60,-117,23,67,-126,-93,-76,27,1,-100,-36,-29,-68,-108,41,-86,-118,-78,18,41,94,-53,71,-75,8,91,46,-80,-50,-21,20,-74,58,-108,-32,-25,-37,-51,-2,-127,93,-82,-93,-16,69,46,20,10,94,-43,-99,127,-74,-84,84,0,31,-40,12,59,41,76,90,127,-58,-77,64,-46,112,83,-106,10,-29,105,-105,57,-73,-49,64,-107,-91,-62,-95,-55,109,-69,110,-94,-101,-24,-40,-92,55,-99,-43,76,28,-29,-40,-30,-22,-54,-81,15,-14,-15,112,28,108,-45,97,-50,82,28,-89,120,-50,122,117,9,-55,-105,120,74,-24,75,56,39,-2,19,-90,43,-112,56,-4,-117,51,47,16,-123,111,126,54,-53,-124,-64,-94,80,-78,-24,-122,36,90,-28,-21,-100,71,2,-60,53,-55,42,-65,-59,-64,-63,-63,98,76,-109,100,89,-74,-58,-112,-5,-84,116,-37,-105,-117,65,94,-65,-58,-117,-68,113,-49,-118,46,-88,-54,70,-53,86,72,-77,39,-82,79,-25,117,19,-46,-73,118,81,-39,-42,21,-125,52,-35,66,21,-99,-105,-60,-12,-83,84,6,121,-23,-122,-93,48,43,36,-112,-54,62,43,-91,-65,-66,-101,-125,-68,-64,111,-60,-49,-5,-1,-50,79,112,52,-33,-73,-5,-8,-105,45,-40,15,-20,91,-71,-79,-18,122,67,118,-78,49,-55,97,-10,6,-55,89,-47,-95,80,-18,-113,39,-106,-25,-121,-3,-81,-123,-3,107,-118,-86,80,50,-71,-34,99,-65,-27,11,123,-113,59,94,112,59,-101,-98,121,65,-5,-84,-43,-71,-13,38,94,-81,-61,-115,-90,25,-68,47,-63,-99,-60,-105,-102,66,-18,75,32,-13,37,-16,-4,-2,-24,55,93,-71,12,36,-82,92,122,-125,-32,108,-40,-15,120,127,116,-109,31,-94,-35,-110,12,-47,30,120,-83,-50,108,-32,127,110,24,95,6,-53,-9,-90,-3,-65,58,-97,89,-27,-121,-113,-4,-74,-84,81,86,-58,17,101,5,23,-54,33,101,85,-29,20,126,66,89,-63,-33,39,73,43,-3,-41,-92,85,-50,66,125,-98,-76,-54,57,-82,127,69,90,25,123,50,74,117,-10,100,-108,-128,-76,-86,-20,-64,72,64,90,33,70,90,53,-55,89,125,85,-54,7,-23,-4,-3,117,98,-108,-113,-125,-8,119,-27,-87,81,62,22,66,39,78,-7,-24,26,79,124,-98,26,-27,-125,-48,17,113,120,106,-108,-113,-61,111,-28,-109,-93,124,44,62,-117,78,-116,-14,113,-43,-93,26,-9,-28,40,31,75,-27,121,-73,19,-92,124,44,126,51,-97,32,-27,99,-13,-44,-37,9,82,62,38,127,36,-99,32,-27,-29,30,-47,86,95,-97,-14,41,-33,-14,-115,-110,62,-59,-77,-108,39,125,10,-23,79,73,-97,-39,-92,-50,-24,-120,56,-97,-33,-90,-123,12,83,-1,21,45,-92,33,1,115,116,-56,11,25,34,94,-56,-74,63,-59,11,-79,95,43,-72,119,-87,-50,-1,-112,-73,-69,-52,-66,-119,-95,-26,-35,-4,38,-122,-66,-119,-95,-1,27,49,4,-97,31,15,0,-88,84"
```

Is there a better Option for reducing the number of characters in a string without converting it to byte array and unwanted characters?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The compression performance you're asking for is absurd. You say "at least 30%", but if you want to compress 751396 characters down to 1500 characters, you want to compress your data down to 0.2% of its original size, getting rid of 99.8% of its bulk. Unless your data is incredibly repetitive, or you can get away with just storing cryptographic hashes of your data and losing decompression capability, this is going to be impossible.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem in having those symbols in the compressed string. As long as the compressed string can be decompressed successfully, who cares for those characters? 
Are you trying to read the compressed string? Can't you just transfer it as is to the receiver and decompress it there?

Comment: Yes, Thanks Burno. There is a channel in the transmission system I am using which is not allowed to receive any other charaters than the above mentioned ones for certain security reason. So I am only left with the options of using alpha-numeric characters and these symbols  [+,-,*,/,!,@,#]. So is it possible to have certain techniques for such scenerio? Thanks for getting deep into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compress to a byte[] and then encode the result in Base64.  This will only use alphanumeric and  fewer symbols which are safe for transfering as text. i.e. it is widely used for this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (sb.length() < 751396)
        sb.append("Size: ").append(sb.length()).append("\n");
    String s = sb.toString();

    String s2 = deflateBase64(s);
    System.out.println("Uncompressed size = " + s.length() + ", compressed size=" + s2.length());

    String s3 = inflateBase64(s2);
    System.out.println("Same after inflating is " + s3.equals(s));
}

public static String deflateBase64(String text) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new DeflaterOutputStream(baos))) {
            writer.write(text);
        }
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

public static String inflateBase64(String base64) {
    try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(
            new InflaterInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(
                            Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64))))) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        char[] chars = new char[1024];
        for (int len; (len = reader.read(chars)) > 0; )
            sw.write(chars, 0, len);
        return sw.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Uncompressed size = 751400, compressed size=219564
Same after inflating is true
```

Comment: Doing that means that the compression algorithm has to at least provide 33% compression, otherwise this is a net-loss. For normal text that's easily achievable though - [this](https://binfalse.de/2011/04/04/comparison-of-compression/) shows a 70% compression ratio. For additional efficiency there'd base85 - not an actual standard though and it's not particularly common (the only standard library I know that includes it, is Python's).

Comment: @Voo I have added some code, but you are right,that limiting yourself to a small set of printable characters means you need to have more of them to store the information.

Comment: Thanks Peter, This code helps me to compress and decompress the string and the scenerios which I have tested are all working. Thanks for the Info and answer

Comment: Hi Voo, is there any jar or library for using base85 in java? If so please share me some links thanks.

Comment: @Kalyan I'm sure there is some, but I never used it so no idea. Beware that it's not a real standard, although [it seems to not be that uncommon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85). It's pretty straight forward to implement though.#

Comment: @KalyanPradhan ideally, if you know which symbols are allowed, you would implement a baseN using exactly all the symbols you can to make it as small as possible.

Comment: Thanks @Voo I will try to find some code related to this.

Comment: Thanks peter, This is a new concept for me to compress and decompress the strings. Can you please share a sample code for implementing baseN in this scenerio? Thanks for all your support.

Comment: Thanks, Peter and voo this kind of solves my problem for now. I will further do research on base N compression algorithm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Deflater` a little more:

```
public static byte[] compress(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION, true);
    //...
}
```

So you'll have the strongest compression **and** you'll skip some of the header data. This is the best you can do with the builtin algorithms.

Comment: Thanks Tamas, This is compressing the data a little more. I will try out the other options in the library.

Comment: This is okay if I have the option of returning an array of bytecodes. But in my case I have to return a string of compressed characters.

Comment: @KalyanPradhan You can turn a byte array into a string. It's just won't be too readable. I.e. you can't add them to an xml. Peter Lawrey gave you the solution for this problem: Base64 is just right for this.

Comment: Yes Base64 is a nice solution which I find now. I will consider using Base N in future but this kind of solves my problem for now, Thanks